# How do i apply 'page control' to images and make an automatic slideshow?

Tags: xcode, imageview, uipagecontrol

i want to a apply a page control section within one of my controllers and make an automatic slideshow from this. If you would like to see what i mean, look at the application - Goal.com app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this I hope it'l helps you,

```
 UIScrollView *scrollView;
-(void)animation{    
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 delay:5 options:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear
                 animations:^{
                     [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(index*320, 0)];

                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished)
 {
     index++;
     [self animation];
 }];
}
```

in the above code index is an integer value for changing the scroll view offset and give the `delay` time whatever you want.